# Is there any way to sort out the problem of delay or (lag) in rendering? in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

Actually, I made a drag and drop component in my application. And the problem I faced is when I drop a picture in that component, it doesn't render on the screen. But on next go it render the picture that I uploaded last time and vice versa.

```
    <div className="uf-upload-box" style={{"text-align":"center", "padding-top":"30px"}} 
    onDrop={onChangeHandler}>

    const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    console.log("Hello");
    setIsLoading(true);
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        fabric.Image.fromURL(reader.result, function (img) {
            setIsLoading(false);
            console.log(img);
            activeCanvas.add(img);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could share more of your code. For example, how you are managing the component state?
However, this problem indicates the UI is getting updated via `setIsLoading(false)` before the image is actually added to activeCanvas.

Now what is activeCanvas? If it is an array of images, you can do something like this:

```
const [activeCanvas , setActiveCanvas] = useState([]);
```

And as the image is loaded successfully:

```
reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(reader.result, function (img) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setActiveCanvas([...activeCanvas , img]);
    });
});
```

Comment: setIsLoading() is a state that is handled within the component, it is responsible for the rendering of (Loading Spinner) only. I'm using activeCanvas from store

Comment: This whole problem is a sign of inappropriate usage of state management. You are updating your activeCanvas but react is not picking up the change until the component is re-rendered in some other way. if you're using redux you must make sure you're updating your global state via `dispatch` and `reducers`

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out the issue that I faced, what I did is; just change the event on dropping the file from ondrop to onChange. And I got the desired result.

replace this one:

```
    onDrop={onChangeHandler}
```

from this one:

```
    onChange={onChangeHandler}
```